# Trouble with adding up by Interior.ColorIndex and Cell Styles

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having trouble tallying cells by Interior.ColorIndex and Cell Style. I'm using an Offset to check another column and a For loop to check each cell. I believe its a problem with my If statements. Shouldn't this work because the loop checks each cell running through all of the If statements?

```
Sub Totals()
Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
Dim Supertotal As Long
Dim Subtotal As Long
Dim Ptotal As Long
Set rng = Range("F2:F32")
Supertotal = 0
Subtotal = 0
Ptotal = 0
For Each cell In rng
    If ActiveCell.Offset(0, -4).Interior.ColorIndex = 6 Then
        Supertotal = Supertotal + 1
    ElseIf ActiveCell.Offset(0, -4).Style = "Note" Then
        Subtotal = Subtotal + 1
    Else
        Ptotal = Ptotal + 1
    End If
Next cell
Ptotal = Ptotal - Supertotal - Subtotal
MsgBox "The Total Number of SuperTests is " & Supertotal
MsgBox "The Total Number of SubTests is " & Subtotal
MsgBox "The Total Number of Procedure Tests is " & Ptotal

End Sub
```

As far as results go I've counted up all 31 cells, they just don't sort out. All 31 cells fall into single variable depending on what I change.

[Excel Data Being Used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6CdBG.png)

Comment: Prima facie you need to fix `ActiveCell.Offset(0, -4)` to `cell.Offset(0, -4)` inside `For..Next` loop.

Answer (score 1):

The loop goes through cells in `rng`, but `If`s are all based on `ActiveCell`, which is selected cell in your worksheet and has nothing in common with `cell`. Instead, use `cell.Offset...`.

Answer (score 0):

Just found an answer to my own problem but thank you for answering.
I Changed The ActiveCell Offsets to Looking for Range("C" & cell.Row).

```
Sub Totals()
Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
Dim Supertotal As Long
Dim Subtotal As Long
Dim Ptotal As Long
Set rng = Range("F2:F32")
Supertotal = 0
Subtotal = 0
Ptotal = 0
For Each cell In rng
    If Range("C" & cell.Row).Interior.ColorIndex = 6 Then
        Supertotal = Supertotal + 1
    ElseIf Range("C" & cell.Row).Style = "Note" Then
        Subtotal = Subtotal + 1
    Else
        Ptotal = Ptotal + 1
    End If
Next cell
MsgBox "The Total Number of SuperTests is " & Supertotal
MsgBox "The Total Number of SubTests is " & Subtotal
MsgBox "The Total Number of Procedure Tests is " & Ptotal

End Sub
```